# Alterar a cor de um slot de tempo específico no Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

Eu estou trabalhando com a view agendaDay no FullCalendar. Eu tenho uma função que bloqueia quando o usuário clica em slots de tempo específicos, em dias específicos (esses valores são gravados no banco). Gostaria de saber como posso definir uma cor diferente apenas para determinados slots de tempo em um dia, especificamente, para as linhas bloqueadas. Como posso identificar uma linha de tempo específica para mudar a sua cor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que melhor atendeu meu problema foi a sugerida neste link do Stackoverflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473143/set-different-color-to-specific-time-slots-in-fullcalendar.

Utilizei uma função javascript mais ou menos como a que segue abaixo. Para dar certo é preciso configurar o intervalo dos slots de tempo de modo a aparecer o rótulo da hora para as linhas. Visto que se colocamos a duração dos slots como 00:15:00 ou 00:00:30:00, 00:45:00 os rótulos das linhas não aparecem, deve-se acrescentar 1 segundo ao final da duração do slot: 00:15:01. Segue o código sugerido:

```
$('tr').find('span').each( function(){
   var timeSlot = $(this).text();
   if(timeSlot> 13 && timeSlot < 18)    //Change 13 and 18 according to what you need
   $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez utilizar as *annotations* possa servir para o que você precisa.

Para adicionar as *annotations*:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ....
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        }
    ],
    annotations: [{
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 15, 30),
        title: 'My 1st annotation', //OPCIONAL
        cls: 'open', //OPCIONAL
        color: '#777777', //OPCIONAL
        background: '#eeeeff' //OPCIONAL
    }, { proxima annotation }, ...]        
});
```

Mais exemplos e os arquivos de suporte dessa feature nesse link:
https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar/blob/master/demos/annotations.html

Resultado final:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]